# List of numbers from database if else

Tags: php, mysql

I have my database like this:

**table**: users

**column**: day1, day2, day3, day4, day5

**row**: null, 1, 1, 1, null

here is what im trying to do:

```
if($row['day1'] == null) {
    $totalNullDays = '1' // '1' is for day1
}
if($row['day2'] == null) {
    $totalNullDays = '2' // '2' is for day2
}
etc...
```

At the end, i want something like this in this format:

```
$totalNullDays = '1, 5'; // because day1 and day5 are null.
```

what is the best way to do this? thanks.

Comment: A schema of that sort violates the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). In any case, if you're concerned about "performance" you'd only need to worry if that was inside a massive loop (e.g. millions of iterations) otherwise the overhead will be immeasurably small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array, and then combine them with `implode()`. And rather than repeat all the same code for each day, use a loop.

```
$nullDays = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    if ($row['day' . $i] === null) {
        $nullDays[] = $i;
    }
}
$totalNullDays = implode(', ', $nullDays);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this way:

```
$arrTotalNullDays = array();    
if($row['day1'] == null) {
  $arrTotalNullDays[] = '1' // '1' is for day1
}
if($row['day2'] == null) {
  $arrTotalNullDays[] = '2' // '2' is for day2
}
$totalNullDays = implode(', ', arrTotalNullDays);
```

Comment: Ops, same answer just before. And also a better one.